# ORA-25226 Trying to dequeue from an exception queue

Tags: oracle, advanced-queuing

When I try to dequeue a message from exception queue I got the following error:

```
ORA-25226: dequeue failed, queue string.string is not enabled for dequeue
```

Queue is created, I have the exception queue there on queue table but I am not able to get that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It is needed to start the exception queue also.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE('AQUSER.event_message_queue_ex_q', true, true);
```

Comment: I don't know from which version, but you cannot enqueue to exception queue, so second parameter should be set to false to avoid ORA-24017